# Unable to access .rdata files in a package

Tags: r, opencpu

I am trying to host a predictive model web service on OpenCPU.  I created the model using R and saved it using the save() command to an .RData file.  Now I want to host this model as a REST web service on OpenCPU.  To that end, I've created an R package with the .RData file in the "data" folder.  Here's what my function looks like:

```
getPrediction <- function() {
  newdf <- data.frame(hp=100, mpg=20, gear=4)
  load("./data/m1.RData")
  y <- predict(m1, newdata = newdf)
  return(y)
}
```

However, the load function fails when testing using OpenCPU tester with "cannot open the connection" error which tells me that the .RData file is unable to be located.

Question.  Am I on the right path as far as usage of OpenCPU goes?  Any thoughts on how I can get around this issue?

Comment: installed packages won't have .rdata files in the data directory. if there are data sets in the `data/` directory, why aren't they accessible to you? did you try `data(m1)`? or you need to put the in your `inst/extdata` directory, the you can `load(system.file('extdata'. 'm1.Rdata', package = 'yourpackage'))`

Comment: m1 is not a data set.  It's a model file I saved so that it can be reused for predictions.  Here's the code for creating m1:  `m1 <- lm(vs ~ hp+mpg+gear, data = mtcars)` and then `save(m1, file="c:\\projects\\myr\\m1.RData")`.  The intention is to host this model in OpenCPU as a restful web service.

Comment: regardless, put it in `inst/something` and you can load it using the command above. the error most likely means your relative file path is wrong

Comment: Thank you.  I changed the location of my model file to be in inst and then used the system.file function as you suggested.  That worked.  If you want to post your comment as an answer, happy to up-vote it.  Thanks again!